# save the record of bulk sms sent into db laravel

Tags: database, laravel, bulksms

i have taken the id and mobile_num from users table.i have to insert that id name in this table as user_id,mobile_num,and status(0,1) into another table(wc_sms_status).sendSMSFunction is working fine.

```
  public function SendBulkSms()
  {  
    $usersNumber = User::select('id','mobile_num')->whereIn('id', [5,6,7,8])->get();  
    foreach($usersNumber as $userNumber)
    {  
    if (!$userNumber->mobile_num) 
    {
        $this->sendSmsFunction($userNumber->mobile_num);  
        DB::table('wc_sms_status')->insert([
            ['user_id' => 'id'],
            ['mobile_num' => 'mobile_num'] // set the status=1 // how query can be changed?
        ]);
       
    } 
    elseif($userNumber->mobile_num == exist && status == 0)
    {
        $this->sendSmsFunction($userNumber->mobile_num);
        $this->save();
    }
    else{

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having ?

Comment: `['user_id' => 'id'],` is just gonna save the text "id" in this field. You need to put a variable here, as well as in `mobile_num`.

Comment: check the commented line in code

Comment: @ceejayoz which variable is used?as $userNumber contain both(id,mobile_num)...can i write this ['user_id' => '$userNumber->'id']

Comment: You'd be using `$userNumber->id` and `$userNumber->mobile_num`.

Comment: You want to insert data instead of `['user_id' => 'id']`, `['mobile_num' => 'mobile_num']`, right ?

Comment: @Atika insert into wc_sms_status (user_id,mobile_num) values ($id,$mobile_num) set status=1 how this query be wriiten in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
    public function SendBulkSms()
      {  
//assuming there is a relationship between your model users and wc_sms_status called wcSmsStatus

        $usersNumber = User::with('wcSmsStatus')->select('id','mobile_num')->whereIn('id', [5,6,7,8])->get();  
        foreach($usersNumber as $userNumber)
        {  
          if (!$userNumber->mobile_num) 
            {
                $this->sendSmsFunction($userNumber->mobile_num);  
                DB::table('wc_sms_status')->insert([
                    'user_id' => $userNumber->id,
                    'mobile_num' => $userNumber->mobile_num, 
                    'status' => 1, 
                ]);
            } elseif ($userNumber->mobile_num && $userNumber['wcSmsStatus']->status === 0)
                {
                   $this->sendSmsFunction($userNumber->mobile_num);
                   $this->save();
                } else {
    
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the elseif($userNumber->mobile_num == exist && status == 0) where i used the exist what would be placed instead of exist if i have to check whether this number is in the table or not?

Comment: Try : `elseif ($userNumber->mobile_num && status === 0)`

Comment: it should be the variable rather than status...status is the column name in the table

Comment: I edit my post, I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: status is not in the user table,,,we are inserting it into wc_sms_status

Comment: Have you created a model for the **wc_sms_status** table ? I edit again my post

Answer (score 0):

```
public function SendBulkSms()
{
    $users = User::select('id','mobile_num')
        ->whereIn('id', [5,6,7,8])
        ->whereNotNull('mobile_num')
        ->get();

    $bulkData = [];
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $this->sendSmsFunction($userNumber->mobile_num);
        DB::table('wc_sms_status')->insert([
            ['user_id' => 'id'],
            ['mobile_num' => 'mobile_num'] // set the status=1 // how query can be changed?
        ]);
        $bulkData[] = [
            'user_id'        => $user->id,
            'mobile_num'     => $user->mobile_num,
        ];
    }

    if (!empty($bulkData)) {
        WcSmsStatus::insert($education);  // change to your model name
        unset($bulkData);
    }
}
```

try to use in this way, it will insert bulk data, dont fergot to mention protected $fillable[] in model